# How can I discover Windows hosts to add a printer

Tags: network, windows, printing

I have a Windows print server on the network. I am trying to one of the printers on this server to a Mac with the latest OSX. I can ping the Windows PC, but when I go to the Windows tab in the add printers window, the PC doesn't show up.

Is there any way to make OSX discover all hosts on the network? I've tried the following command as suggested in a similar question on Super-User:

```
arp -a
```

But to no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this one is time. I gave the Mac about 30 minutes and when I went back to it, it had found my print server. It's a shame there is no button to tell the Mac to discover devices on the network.

Comment: I am CONSTANTLY amazed at how crappy Apple's networking is compared to Windows. I do believe it **was** "discovering" Windows print servers. It just took too long doing so...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a real answer but I have been using Macs in (mostly) PC environments and I find the best way to print to it is by setting up a printer using it's IP address.

I rarely have any success printing thru a Windows print queue, and unless there is a rule that you HAVE to print thru the Windows server save yourself the hassle and just print directly.

Comment: Hi, I had considered that but really we want the Macs to use the same queues as our Windows users. I've also posted an answer. Thanks.